# Relation between 3 tables in Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, relationship

I have three tables :

```
PLAYERS with a team_id

TEAMS

SCORES with a player_id
```

The thing is :

My teams have players who have scores and I would like to make a ranking of teams. So basically get the best score by players and make the sum of it if a team has several players.

For example :

TEAM A has player 1 and player 2. 
Player 1 has 3 scores (300, 150 and 500 for example) and I'd like to keep only the best one (so 500).

Do you have any idea how I can do that ?
As there's no direct relation between teams and scores or between players and scores, I don't understand how I can make the link between these 3.

Thanks for your help !

**EDIT**

Score Model

```
class Score extends Model
{
protected $fillable = [
    'value', 'player_id'
];

public function player()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Player');
}

public function players_scores()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Team', 'App\Player');
}
```

}

Player model

```
class Player extends Model
{
protected $fillable = [
  'name','email','team_id'
];

/**
 * Get the team of the player
 */
public function team()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Team');
}

/**
 * Get the scores of the player
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
 */
public function scores()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Score');
}

/**
 * Get the maximum score from the player
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getBestScoreAttribute()
{
    return $this->scores->max('value');
}


}
```

Team model

```
class Team extends Model
{
protected $fillable = ['name','logo'];

protected $appends = ['score'];

public function players()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Player');
}

/*
 * Collect all the team players scores
 */
public function players_scores()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Score', 'App\Player');
}

public function scores()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Score');
}

/*
 * Sum the score of all team players to get the team score
 */
public function getScoreAttribute()
{
    return $this->players_scores->sum('value');
}   

}
```

Comment: so you want to get the best scores of all players in a team, sum them and store it under particular team. right?

Comment: Yes exactly ! :)

Answer (score 0):

First you should have defined a `hasMany` function on the `Player` model pointing to the `Score` model. Then you can query the `Player`'s best score by doing `$player->scores()->max('value')` (assuming that `$value` is the attribute that holds the actual score value in the `Score` model).

Once you have that, you can use that snippet for defining [an accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators), that way you can do something like `$player->bestScore` for getting the maximum score for a player.

Then having a way yo query the Player's best score, you should have defined a `HasMany` relationship on the `Team` model pointing to the `Player` model. The query for getting the team score would be like `$team->players->sum('max_score')`. You can also define a mutator for this attribute so you can access this snippet like `$team->score`.

Finally, for ordering all teams it would be:

```
  return Team::all()->sortByDesc('score');
```

Comment: I already have a hasMany function on the Player model. Where should I define the accessor ? On the team model ? I'm kinda lost :( but thanks for your help !  (I added the models in my post)

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple way

First select all the players of a particular team like

```
$players=PLAYERS::where('team_id',1)->get();//1 is a sample value pass your team_id
```

Then use foreach to iterate each player id and get the highest score

```
foreach($players as $player)
{
   $score=SCORES::where('player_id',$player)->orderBy('score', 'desc')->value('score'); // gets only the highest score of the player
   $total=$total+$score;//Sum of the highest score
}
```

Then if you want to insert into the table means

```
TEAMS::create(['team_id'=>1,'score'=>$total]);
```

Hope it helps:)

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't work :( but thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

In case someone has the same issue, I found the solution :

```
static function getDailyTeams(int $limit = 10)
{        
    $callback = function($query) {
        $query->whereDate('scores.created_at', date('Y-m-d'));
    };
    $player = function($query) use ($callback) {
        $query->whereHas('scores', $callback)->with(['scores' => $callback]);
    };
    $teams = Team::with(['players' => $player])->get()->sortByDesc(function ($team) {
        return $team->players->sum('best_score');
    }
    );
    return $teams;  
}
```